# Graph embeddable in g-torus (not using Euler)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I would like to know, if there is another way (beside the generalized Euler theorem) to know if a graph is NOT embeddable in a g-torus.

Comment: Initially I was interested in this because I was trying to find a Heegaard diagram for a representable presentation. I realized that to do this I could check if another associated a graph to the presentation is planar, instead of checking if a graph is embeddable in the two torus. Still I believe this question is interesting in general, so I will not close it.